# C# PHP Connection Flood Protection

Tags: c#, php, mysql

So let's say I created a feedback form in C#.
It sens the feedback to my PHP Page and my PHP Page adds it to my MySQL Database.
Code:

```
private void PostFeed(string Params)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers["Accept"] = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        wc.Headers["Accept-Language"] = @"en-US,en;q=0.5";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString("http://website/feedtest.php", "POST", Params);
        Console.WriteLine(HtmlResult);
    }
}
```

On my PHP I have a code that looks similar to:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$desc = $_REQUEST['description'];
connect
post result...
close connection
```

The question I have is: is there a way to protect against flood ? I understand anyone can just spam/flood it by sending feedback continuously or even creating a third party app that sends like 1000 post request per second. I was thinking of implementing some sort of check on the PHP side, for example: if the connection password from the c# app matches, then continue if not, exit.

Basically, I dont want people to take advantage of the feedback method and spam me.

Can anyone suggest a method ? or Should I not even worry about this ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you close the connection on every request? You should be using connection pooling at the very least.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on connection pooling ? Do you mean that my PHP will stay connected to MySQL and it'll just send query result ?

Comment: A library like PDO has [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) that avoid having to reconnect on every page load. You absolutely *must* do this or your application will be brutally slow. These connections stay open between requests so that they are ready to go the instant a request is received. It takes as long as a second to connect to and authenticate with a database, but once that connection is established, results are almost immediate.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I will activate persistent connections. so does that mean in the end, i dont need to close the connection? Also, I noticed that you said "at the very least"; Do you have any other recommendation for faster performance ?

Comment: The connection pool will take care of recycling your database handles, so you don't need to worry about it. Faster performance comes from being smart about what queries you're executing and avoiding those that are measurably problematic. Don't fret until you have tangible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical technique is to have some kind of submissions per X unit of time limit where you have a `last_submitted_at` column in a table associated with some kind of identifier. For example, you might associate it with a user if you have a fairly robust user registration system, or you might associate it with an IP if you don't.

This is the system that Stack Overflow uses if you try and vote, post, or as questions too often. Each of these has a separate timer which probably translates to a separate `last_X_at` column in the database somewhere.

If the last time is less than some threshold, present an error instead of accepting the submission.